# Using redis cache read replicas in AWS ECS with symfony

Tags: amazon-web-services, symfony, redis, amazon-ecs, amazon-elasticache

Does anyone have experience running redis cache in AWS ECS with several read-replicas for different availability zones within a Symfony application?

We noticed that the performance of redis cache is pretty bad if the web-service and the redis-cache service are located in different AZs (redis requests took about 4 times longer), so our current approach would be to have a single write-node and several read replicas for each  AZ.

Is there a way to configure this behaviour in symfony cache pools?

A simple cache-chaining would results in errors for the reader nodes I assume ... https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/adapters/chain_adapter.html

Configuration of several read-replicas with cluster mode disabled: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Replication.Redis-RedisCluster.html

Comment: You linked to some ElastiCache documentation, and tagged the question with ElastiCache, but your question says you are running Redis on ECS, not ElastiCache. Can you clarify how exactly you are running Redis?

Comment: We are currently using elasticache with redis engine in v7.0.7 in non cluster mode and non multi-az single node.

Comment: the symfony application runs in ecs for clarification